# Controlling Soundcloud Custom Player with HTML5 widget

Tags: soundcloud

I have a question about the Custom Player. (http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/custom-player#)

The docs say that the Custom Player can be controlled using the Widgets API (http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget) which I'm familiar with.

But the widgets API requires an iframe when you instantiate it... and the Custom Player doesn't seem to use an iframe.

I have my Custom Player in a div with the "sc-player" class. How would I create an SC.Widget out of it to control it? So far I've been faking clicks, which is definitely not the way to go.